# how to fetch a consonant cluster and transform the word using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, arrays

If a word begins with a consonant, take the first consonant or consonant cluster and move to end of this word

the input of the program

```
blanket
sting
```

the output of the program

```
anketbl
ingst
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to understand the meaning of the concept of "consonant cluster" linguistically: It's a consonant sequence sounds in a row. for example the word "blanket" is a consonant cluster with 2 consonant sounds "bl" .. and the word "strict" is a consonant cluster with 3 consonant sound "str"
So, for words begin with consonant sounds, the sound should be moved to the end of this word. And the fetch will be based on the vowels that follow the consonant sound like this

```
function moveToEnd(string) {
  // the variable index is going to store the first vowel found in the string
  let index = 0;

  for (let c of string) {
    // Loop through the string until the first vowel has been found
    if ('aeiou'.includes(c)) {
      index = string.indexOf(c);
      // once we find the index of the first vowel we jump out of the loop
      break;
    }
  }
  // the new String
  return string.slice(index) + string.slice(0, index);
}
console.log(moveToEnd('blanket')) //---> output: ankletbl
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let input = 'any string', vowel = [],consonant=[]
input.split('').forEach(e => {
if(/[aeiouwy]/gi.test(e)){
vowel.push(e)
}
else if(!/[aeiouwy]/gi.test(e)){consonant.push(e)}
})
console.log([...vowel,...consonant].toString())
```

Comment: This does not provide a solution to the OP's problem. You're just separating vowels and consonants into separate arrays, and a bit sloppily not accounting for whitespace or joining the letters back together. The OP needed to shift the initial consonant cluster of individual words to the end of the word, this answer doesn't address that problem.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.